# Why popup of wpf app is being closed on xenapp?

Tags: c#, wpf, citrix, xenapp

I am trying to run a wpf application on Xen-app but popup of application is being closed immediately after clicking on text-box of popup in few machine.

Every thing works fine on normal system. Even in Xen-Desktop every thing works fine.

Can any one put some comment what can be the reason?

Comment: does your app write any logs ?

Comment: @FelixD.Yes, and log is working fine.I am taking login input using popup but as soon as I click on text-box, popup is being closed.

Comment: did you subscribe to unhandled exceptions ? it sounds like your app is crashing rather than just not displaying the window :/

Comment: I have handled exceptions and writing logs in case of exceptions. App is displaying window as well as popup, but popup are closing with mouse click on any where on popup.